Convert code from VB 2010 to VB 2017 I got one single error
I just trying to convert this old code VB 2010 to my compiler vb2017 and I got this Error:  BC30455 Argument not specified for parameter 'connStr' of 'Public Sub New(connStr As String)' Line 29. I can't find a way how to solve this eror to compile.Thank you
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    ' First approach: 
    ' Create a case sensitive database by using the SqlCeEngine 
    ' constructor.
    If File.Exists("Test.sdf") Then
        File.Delete("Test.sdf")
    End If

    ' 1033: specifies the English locale with collation 
    ' SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
    Dim connStr As String = "Data Source='Test.sdf'; LCID=1033; Case Sensitive = TRUE"

    Dim engine As New SqlCeEngine(connStr)
    engine.CreateDatabase()
    engine.Dispose()

    ' Second approach: 
    ' Create a case-sensitive database by using the LocalConnectionString 
    ' property. 
    If File.Exists("Test.sdf") Then
        File.Delete("Test.sdf")
    End If

    Dim engine2 As New SqlCeEngine
    engine2.LocalConnectionString =
        "Data Source='Test.sdf'; LCID=1033; Case Sensitive = TRUE"
    ' 1033: specifies the English locale with collation 
    ' SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
    engine2.CreateDatabase()
    engine2.Dispose()

    Dim conn As SqlCeConnection = Nothing

    Try
        conn = New SqlCeConnection(connStr)
        conn.Open()

        'Retrieve the connection string information - 
        ' notice the 'Case Sensitive' value
        Dim dbinfo As List(Of KeyValuePair(Of String, String)) = conn.GetDatabaseInfo

        Console.WriteLine(ChrW(10) & "GetDatabaseInfo() results:")

        Dim kvp As KeyValuePair(Of String, String)

        For Each kvp In dbinfo
            Console.WriteLine(kvp)
        Next
    Catch ex As Exception
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
    Finally
        conn.Close()
        Console.WriteLine(vbNewLine & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Press any key to continue...")
        Console.Read()
    End Try

End Sub
End Class

I spect to delete a database if exist before create a new database.

Which line is 29?

VB.NET 2017 is fundamentally the same language as VB.NET 2010 - in fact it's a superset, so you really don't need to "convert" anything: VB.NET 2022 can compile and run any VB.NET program going back to VB.NET 2002 without requiring you to make any source-changes (now, maybe some build system changes, but that's different). But the main problem here is your use of SQL-CE (which is EOL now) - you should switch over to Sqlite or full-fat MSSQL.

@Dai without requiring you to make any source-changes ( that is absolutly wrong and depends on the code

@nbk, it actually is true, as long as you are using the same language version and targeting the same framework. If you change the language version or framework then you may have to change the code, even if you're using the same IDE version.

@nbk I used to work on Visual Studio, not that that fact has relevance here - but if you’re going to contradict me then please link to an example or documentation that supports your case. Anyway; I’ll concede one thing: subsequent VB.NET language versions did introduce new keywords which may conflict with user identifier names - but that’s only a potential problem if you changed your vbproj to use a floating langversion. If you specify an exact version (which is the default, IIRC) then you won’t get new keyword conflicts and my point stands.

I notice that you are using two different SqlCeEngine constructors for no apparent reason. Why set the connection string for the second via a property when you set the first by a constructor parameter? Seems like you should be doing both the same way. If the second of those constructors is on line 29, that would presumably fix your error too.

The following may be of interest: SqlCeEngine.

You create engine using a connStr parameter:
Dim engine As New SqlCeEngine(connStr)

If you want to solve this compilation error, you can create engine2 the same way:
Dim engine2 As New SqlCeEngine(connStr)

